# How to display HD Youtube Playlist Videos with CefSharp in WPF window

Tags: wpf, iframe, youtube, cefsharp, youtube-iframe-api

I have these problem for quite some time now. At first I thought it requieres some time until youtube videos HD quality is available, but is already 2 weeks since that and nothing had change.

I have 2 different youtube PlayList(all videos uploaded in **HD**) that work different, one in **HD** an the other in **SD**, in a web project that is displayed in a WPF window with CefSharp.

I tried everything but I could not get this bad quality playlist in HD quality. The default quality in youtube channel is HD and if I open the `index.html` file in any other browser is also HD quality, but only in `Cefsharp` is not displaying the HD option.

**In WPF window with CefSharp:**

**playlist with low quality**

[image]

**playlist with hd quality**

[image]

**In any browser (Mozilla firefox and Edge tested):**

**playlist with low quality**

[image]

**playlist with hd quality**

[image]

After trying all possible settings, but nothing worked.

My currrent Cefsharp nugets:
`CefSharp.Common, CefSharp.Wpf and CefSharp.OffScreen version 109.1.110.`

These are my current codes:

**In Cefsharp settings**

```
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
if (settings.CefCommandLineArgs.ContainsKey("enable-system-flash"))
{
  settings.CefCommandLineArgs["enable-system-flash"] = "0";
}
else
{
  settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-system-flash", "0");
}
var featuresToDisable = "NetworkService,VizDisplayCompositor";
if (WpfUtils.IsDarkThemeUsed())
{
  settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("force-dark-mode", "1");
}
else
{
  featuresToDisable = $"{featuresToDisable},DarkMode";
}
settings.EnableAudio();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server");
//settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-plugins-discovery", "1");
//settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-remote-playback-api", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-sync", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-wake-on-wifi", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-voice-input", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-features", featuresToDisable);
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync");
settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

**In youtube player iframe**

```
vid_frame[m] = new YT.Player('vid_frame' + m, {
            width: '1280',
            height: '720',
            videoId: vidIDs[n][0],
            host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
            playerVars: {
              'html5': 1,
              'showinfo': showVideoInfo,
              'autoplay': 1,
              'disablekb': 1,
              'controls': showPlayerControls,
              'playsinline': 1,
              'modestbranding': 1,
              'hl': 'en-US',
              'rel': showRelatedVideos,
              'widget-referrer': 'resource://web'
        },
            frameborder: 0,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            events: {
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
          });
```

I expect both playlist displaying videos in HD in Cefsharp and the browsers.

Does somebody know what could be the problem?

What are the viewing conditions that make effect in one list but not in the other?, refer to this link:
[iframe_api_reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#october-24,-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolution Problem

There was a mistake when uploading the video in youtube, the format uploaded was `1920x1080`, but it was not enough for the **HD** resolution option in `CefSharp`. After transforming the video into **4K** and upload to youtube, it worked!